# PhpStorm: sync line endings when downloading from a remote server

Tags: git, phpstorm, line-endings

The setup is as following:

- server: UNIX (LF);
- dev-machine: Windows (CRLF);
- Git: autocrlf is enabled.

When downloading a file from the remote server (via PhpStorm deployment feature) it gets LF line endings. It leads to Git marking some files as *changed* although they differ only in line separators. Commit is being clogged by those ghost changes and it's not good.

**Q.** Is there a way to tell PhpStorm to change line endings from LF to CLRF when downloading from the remote host?

Comment: Remember that `autocrlf` can be set at several levels (system, global, local and worktree). Perhaps PhpStorm doesn't roll its own (to be honest, I don't know) but git itself is not configured the way you think. And, anyway, I think you'd prefer to *disable* it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Disabling it will cause problems when checking out on different platforms.

Comment: PhpStorm can change line endings only in opened/edited files. So you can't do that in IDE. I would suggest enabling `core.autocrlf` in git config.

Comment: @Ástþór In my case *LF* line endings is the result of downloading a file from UNIX to Windows via PhpStorm deployment feature. It has nothing to do with Git.

Comment: @DenisKulagin It could be your FTP server settings as IDE does not really change line endings. At very least I do not see that happening in my projects. But I have worked with 2 projects (some cheap shared hosting) where even if downloaded using FileZilla the file will have extra line breaks for no reason (i.e. if viewing directly on a server I see 2 lines one after another; if downloaded I see an extra empty line between them).

Comment: @DenisKulagin P.S. I keep all my files using LF (expect Windows-specific ones, e.g. `.cmd` file or `web.config` for IIS web server). All other are using LF and working just fine on local (IIS) and remote (IIS, Apache, Nginx) web servers.